# Avoid scientific notation created by cut function using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cut, scientific-notation

Considering a sample of my data,

```
> head(sample, 10)
   variable longitude latitude value
1         A      8.43    49.42  1000
2         B      8.92    49.14  2000
3         C      8.53    49.43  3000
4         D     12.25    50.32  4000
5         A     13.86    51.47  5000
6         B      9.01    51.38  6000
7         C      8.18    51.25  7000
8         D      7.66    51.30  8000
9         A     11.99    50.58  9000
10        B     12.15    50.92 10000
```

I have created breaks and bins for the `value` column as follows

```
brks <- c(0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000)
sample <- mutate(sample, bins = cut(value, breaks = brks, right = TRUE))
```

and finally I have plotted the data

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = sample, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size = bins, color = variable))
```

[image]

I want to avoid scientific notation for the `bins` legend by manipulating the `ggplot` commands. Is that possible?

I know that the parameter `dig.lab` is a possible solution if added to the `cut` command, but I am wondering if this can also be achieved by modifying the `ggplot` entries. `options('scipen')` did not work for me.

Comment: You can't use `options('scipen'))` because your labels are text, not numeric. Why don't you want to use `dig.lab`? If you need the labels in scientific notation as well just create two columns: one with each notation.

Comment: @SamR Not against using `dig.lab`, I am just exploring if there is a method to avoid the scientific notation directly in the ggplot code

Comment: You could write a function to pull the numbers from the character vector, format them as you desire and then put them back. I am just struggling to see why you would.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the digits label ie `dig.lab` value. I use 5 since i see that the largest value in bins is 5 digits ie(10000). You can use any number eg 7. Just ensure that the number is greater than or equal to the number of digits in the maximum value

```
sample <- sample %>%
  mutate(bins = cut(value, breaks = brks, right = TRUE, dig.lab=5))

   variable longitude latitude value         bins
1         A      8.43    49.42  1000     (0,2000]
2         B      8.92    49.14  2000     (0,2000]
3         C      8.53    49.43  3000  (2000,4000]
4         D     12.25    50.32  4000  (2000,4000]
5         A     13.86    51.47  5000  (4000,6000]
6         B      9.01    51.38  6000  (4000,6000]
7         C      8.18    51.25  7000  (6000,8000]
8         D      7.66    51.30  8000  (6000,8000]
9         A     11.99    50.58  9000 (8000,10000]
10        B     12.15    50.92 10000 (8000,10000]
```

Then run your `gglplot` code

Comment: kindly read back the last paragraph of my question. I know about `dig.lab`, I am just wondering if there is another method to avoid scientific notation directly in the `ggplot` code.